# createHmac gives two different outputs from Buffer

Tags: node.js, cryptography, hmac

consider this Buffer base64-decoded

```js
const base64decoded = Buffer.from('key', 'base64')
```

Now the two digest below will be different :

```js
crypto.createHmac('sha512', base64decoded)
    .update('test')
    .digest('base64')
// -> QkooamNoTPVTrhrrxkU5r2vnFU3e7DMSJaukjAEugOiBYFnQyxHQDZvy6zMYesNHHyoG78cgW27K2m9+OPuQ6g==
crypto.createHmac('sha512', base64decoded.toString())
    .update('test')
    .digest('base64')
// -> zLSdI2dO7o84v41Z5vbxUUyu6FQSTzWOS3OHf7/iijHZUecDKyFeDGzB3Ei22cO9Zcr8a9AiiRiDiBVb0e+kmw==
```

This really confuses me, I was expecting the same output. How is the `Buffer` used in the `createHmac` to manage to give a different output ?

---

And how should I change my second function so it gives the same output as the first one ?
I try to make a browser port of a node package that makes use of `createHmac`, everything was working nicely but `window.crypto.subtle.sign` (HMAC) is also giving a different output because I can't figure out how to use the Buffer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If no encoding is specified, [`Buffer.toString()`](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buf_tostring_encoding_start_end) converts the buffer content to a string with `utf8` encoding. [`crypto.createHmac`](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/internal/crypto/util.js#L52) uses [`Buffer.from()`](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_class_method_buffer_from_string_encoding) on the key if it is a string type. This function also uses `utf8` encoding by default. So that should work.

However - as you experienced - there is a caveat: the output of `Buffer.from('key', 'base64')` is not valid utf8 data. So converting to `utf8` leads to loss of data. Unfortunately, this [does not throw an error](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/4942).

The best solution would be to stick to the `Buffer`, which is a better representation of raw binary data than a string.

Comment: Thanks bro, it helped me to think my problem, and found a solution !